# MOV instruction with an offset

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Here is a line of assembly code from a core file.

```
0x00002ac8c957012d <+45>:    mov    0x8(%rsp), %rsi
```

I noticed that registry rsp is at the following location so I use the Examine command to view the content plus 16 more objects/bytes.

```
> x/16x 0x2acd5752a610
0x2acd5752a610: 0x70   0xa6   0x11   0xff   0x29   0xcd   0x22   0x00
0x2acd5752a618: 0x33   0xee   0xf1   0xa9   0xb2   0xcc   0x34   0x76
```

When figuring out the offset of 0x8 is this going to be 0 based resulting in the value being 0x33 or just count starting with 1 to 8 from the start which results in the value being 0x00?

Comment: RSP is a register, not a registry... And what tells you that RSP contains 0x2ac8c957012d... that's the address of the `mov` instruction.

Comment: you're loading to RSI, a 64-bit register, so 8 bytes will be loaded, not 1.

Comment: If value in `rsp` is `0x2acd5752a610`, then 8 bytes starting at `0x2acd5752a618` will be loaded into `rsi`, i.e. the low-significant byte (`sil`) will be indeed `0x33`, but the whole `rsi` will be loaded, including following 7 bytes `ee f1 ...`. The`0x00` is at `[rsp+7]`, not involved.

Comment: Thanks, the addition to mention about the other values too was helpful. So, is that entire 64-bit value an address to an actual value?

Answer (score 4):

You are confused by the braindead abomination that is AT&T syntax.

In Intel's intended syntax `mov    0x8(%rsp), %rsi` translates to:

```
mov rsi,[rsp+8]
```

Which means fill the 8 bytes of register `rsi` with the 8 bytes at address `[rsp+8]`.
Note that `rsp` is a 64-bit (8 byte) register which handles 8 bytes at a time.
We don't know what the value of `rsp` is, but we do know that `rsp` is the stack pointer and `+8` means we take the address 8 bytes above the stack pointer, or the second most recently pushed value on the stack (because the stack grows downward).

This instruction is sneaking a peak inside the stack :-)

Comment: Thanks, you also answered the follow-up question I posted that the new value is actually a new register address for rsi in which some value exists.